# Sustituir elemenos de una lista con append en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un problema que me exige usar `append` para sustituir de una lista los números impares por 0 y los pares por 1.

**¿Como podría construir el bucle para lograrlo?**

Comment: ¿necesariamente tienes que utilizar el **append** para sustituir?, es que **append** es para agregar al final de la lista, ¿te sería igual crear una lista nueva e ir agregando los 0 y 1s? y finalmente retornar la nueva lista.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Te recomiendo mirarte [tour] y [ask] para ver como funciona por encima el sitio y cómo formular buenas preguntas. En cuanto a la pregunta en si, supongo que lo que quieres es crear una nueva lista, porque sustituir in-place usando `append` no tiene ni pies ni cabeza cuando podemos asignar un nuevo valor mediante indexado. Por favor, **agrega que has intentado** a la pregunta y si todavía no has intentado nada empieza por ahí, un ciclo `for-in`, un condicional y `list.append` es todo lo que necesitas.

Comment: de hecho, se puede hacer evitando el ciclo* usando recursividad

Answer (score 1):

Con el operador **%** puedes saber si un número es par o impar, aquí te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
    numbers = [0,2,3,4,5,1,2]
    resp = []
    for number in numbers:
        # este es par
        if number % 2 == 0:
            resp.append(1)
        else: 
            resp.append(0)
    return resp
```

En caso que quieras poner a los pares como 0 y los impares como 1 entonces el código quedaría más elegante:

```
numbers = [0,2,3,4,5,1,2]
resp = []
for number in numbers:
    # insertas el valor de la operacion
    resp.append(number % 2)
return resp
```

Comment: Te invito a leer [answer] , cuando la pregunta esta mal formulada se debe esperar a que el usuario actualice ,trata de responder preguntas bien formuladas

Comment: ok @JackNavaRow muchas gracias por la sugerencia.